# Copy static files from Docker container to non empty named volume

Tags: docker, nginx, static, docker-compose, docker-volume

I wanna copy new static files from Docker container via named volume to `nginx` container that has old static.

*Prerequisites*:

**Host machine directory tree**:

```
.
├── data
│   ├── bar.2.css
│   └── foo.2.js
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM busybox:latest
COPY data /data
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  static:
    image: 'myimage'
    volumes: 
      - 'myvolume:/data'

  nginx:
    image: 'nginx'
    volumes: 
      - 'myvolume:/data'

volumes:
  myvolume:
```

Directory tree of named volume **myvolume** with old static:

```
    .
    ├── bar.1.css
    └── foo.1.js
```

*Sequence of steps:*

1. Build `myimage` with Dockerfile: `docker build -t myimage .`
2. Check new static files in `myimage`: `docker run myimage ls /data`

   **bar.2.css
   foo.2.js**
3. Run: `docker-compose up -d --build static`

In my mind it must rebuild service `static` and overwrite old static files. But it did't. Why and how to fix it? Also, what is a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are just coping the new files alongside the old files with the `docker build -t myimage .`

Maybe you can delete the previous data before you insert new, by running a one-time container??

`docker exec -it static rm /data`

and then just copy the new data, or build the new image:

```
docker cp /data static:/data
```

---

You can also, implement the build step inside the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  static:
    build: /
    image: 'myimage'
    volumes: 
      - 'myvolume:/data'

  nginx:
    image: 'nginx'
    volumes: 
      - 'myvolume:/data'

volumes:
  myvolume:
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why** -- I believe that you are mounting the pre-existing volume `myvolume` atop your `/data` folder of the `static` container. This is because your `myvolume` already exists. If `myvolume` did not exist, the content of `/data` would be copied to the volume.

See: [Docker-Volume-Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) --  "If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted (such as /app/ above), the directory’s contents will be copied into the volume."

**Sample Solution**

Give this a shot. With the structure and content below do a:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

This is additive, so if you update/add content to the `newdata` folder and re-run your compose, then the new content will be present in the shared volume.

You can mount and inspect the shared volume, like this:

```
docker run -it --rm --mount type=volume,src={docker-volume-name},target=/shared busybox sh
```

**Environment**

Folder structure:

```
   .
   ├── dockerfile
   ├── docker-compose.yml
   ├── newdata/
       ── apple.txt
       ── banana.txt
```

*dockerfile*

```
FROM busybox:latest

# From host machine to image
COPY newdata/* /newdata/

# @Runtime from image to where a shared volume could be mounted.
ENTRYPOINT [ "cp", "-r", "/newdata/", "/shared" ]
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  data-provider:
    image: data-provider
    build: .
    volumes: 
      - type: volume
        source: so
        target: /shared

  destination:
    image: busybox:latest
    volumes: 
      - type: volume
        source: so
        target: /shared-data
    depends_on: 
      - data-provider
    command: ls -la /shared-data/newdata

volumes:
  so:
```

*Sample Output:*

```
$ docker-compose up --build
Creating volume "sodockervol_so" with default driver
Building data-provider
Step 1/3 : FROM busybox:latest
 ---> c75bebcdd211
Step 2/3 : COPY newdata/* /newdata/
 ---> bc85fc19ed7b
Removing intermediate container 2a39f4be8dd2
Step 3/3 : ENTRYPOINT cp -r /newdata/ /shared
 ---> Running in e755c3179b4f
 ---> 6e79a32bf668
Removing intermediate container e755c3179b4f
Successfully built 6e79a32bf668
Successfully tagged data-provider:latest
Creating sodockervol_data-provider_1 ...
Creating sodockervol_data-provider_1 ... done
Creating sodockervol_destination_1 ...
Creating sodockervol_destination_1 ... done
Attaching to sodockervol_data-provider_1, sodockervol_destination_1
destination_1    | total 16
destination_1    | drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Oct  9 17:50 .
destination_1    | drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Oct  9 17:50 ..
destination_1    | -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            25 Oct  9 17:50 apple.txt
destination_1    | -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            28 Oct  9 17:50 banana.txt
sodockervol_data-provider_1 exited with code 0
sodockervol_destination_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: @A.Innokentiev -- I have included an more complete example answer if you are still interested in this question.